# Could not use both -profile and -format in imagick mogrify

Tags: imagick, mogrify

I could not use both `-format` and `-profile` options together in mogrify.

My command is

```
mogrify -path "output path" -format jpg -profile srgb.icc "input path\*.*"
```

it returns

> mogrify.exe: Not a JPEG file: starts with 0x00 0x00
>   `D:\ssm\Imgtool\bin\srgb.icc' @ error/jpeg.c/JPEGErrorHandler/333.